# Динамическое изменения языка

Tags: javascript, html5

У нас есть небольшой интернет магазин, из базы подгружается описания товара. У сайта есть 3 версии языка `en`, `ru` и `italian`.

Как можно сделать так чтоб, при смене языка описания переводилось на нужный язык, но не создавая в базе 3 версии описания товара.

Возможно можно сделать как-то через `API google translate`, или есть другие решения?

С статичным текстом проблемы нет. Сделал 3 версии страницы и, в зависимости от локации, подгружаю нужную!

Comment: Чтобы реализовать автоматический машинный перевод на базе Google Translate Вам понадобится использовать платное API.

Comment: Можно также разрешить браузеру предлагать пользователю машинный перевод при открытии страницы, но это скажется на SEO, так как для этого (если не ошибаюсь) нужно чтобы язык страницы не совпадал с языком пользователя

Comment: Поэтому лучше всего перевести товары и сделать мультиязычность с помощью подгрузки контента в зависимости от языка пользователя

Comment: При использовании google translate у вас получится второй AliExpress. **Ивонн бразильские странный вьющиеся волосы девственницы**

Comment: вариант с тремя описаниями самый надежный и правильный. да, пусть и более трудозатратный, но полагаться на автоматические переводы не стоит